# Switching Videoclips for VideoPlayer in Unity degrades FPS drastically

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, video-player

I am using the Video player API that unity provides for playing a video on the surface texture. While I am changing the video clip after each update the FPS on the editor is really slow. The switching and loading the new video clip takes a lot of time (500-600 ms)

***videoPlayer.clip = videoClips [vindex];*** //this command used for changing the videoclip

I just put the timer before and after and found it consumes a huge amount of time.

Can anyone please tell me how to reduce the time and increase the FPS. Any alternative way or suggestion will highly be appreciated. (Platform: Unity Editor on windows)

Comment: Why are you changing the video clip after **each** update?

Comment: For designing something, I need to change the video clip as player moves. Each video just has one encoded frame. Is there any way to reduce the delay?

Comment: I don't think so. It's not a good idea to change video clip every frame. Remember that it has to be prepared even before playing it and that also take some time. I think you should re-consider your design and find another way to get your goal accomplished. Since you haven't mentioned what you're trying to make, I don't think I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the videos are really small, you can consider to use multiple videoPlayer to play each video in the same time. Set the **RenderMode** to **RenderTexture**, and switch RenderTexture instead of videoClip.

```
surface.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = videoPlays[vindex].targetTexture;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the suggestions. Actually, my each video clip size is 200-300 KB, and FYI, my render mode is Material Override (not rendertexture). I tried that, it doesn't increase the FPS. Any other suggestions plz?

Comment: How about covert video clip to sprite sheet animation?

Comment: thanks again for ur suggestion. But in my case, the video is 360 deg background panoramic video and video clips will change depending on the player's movement from the current location. So It doesn't seem like sprite-sheet animation will help. No of video clips are also quite large. Any other ways?